# Definition and declaration of a PRIMARY KEY for a temporal table

Tags: database-design, primary-key, duplication, temporal-tables

My teacher gave us an example *bitemporal* table holding rows related to *medical records* to test our homework on. The table has the columns that follow:

- *first name*
- *last name*
- *parameter*
- *value*
- *unit*
- *valid start time* (When parameter/value started being true e.g patient diagnosed with Fever)
- *valid stop time* (When parameter/value stopped being true e.g patient Diagnosed as cured from Fever)
- *transaction time*
- *transaction stop time* (When row was deleted (null if wasn't))

Said table stores, e.g., the following data:

[image]

I think that the PRIMARY KEY (PK) is (*first name, last name, parameter, transaction time*).

The problem here is that there are many rows (almost half a table) where these four columns are equal. For Example:

[image]

What this means is that two rows were INSERTed at the same time for *patient* 'Sima Nice' regarding the parameter 'Tetracyclin'. The only thing that's different are the *valid time* values (because it should be an UPDATE of course).

**Question**

I don't understand how that makes sense. I told my teacher I think it's a mistake but he insists that (a) it's ok, that (b) there are scenarios where this can happen and that (c) the PK of this table should include the *valid time*.

So, what do you say: Is this situation right?

Comment: Either you or your teacher is confused. The table you show has a bitemporal design, but the data you show is not temporal data. You show a many-to-one relationship between the patient and a series of independent events (medication administered, an episode of fever). Temporal data would show an unbroken sequence of state changes such that when one state starts, the previous state ends.

Comment: @TommCatt Thanks for your response. the table is supposed to be temporal because it has Transaction Time column. What I told my teacher is that I think there are duplicates PRIMARY KEYs (first name, last name,  parameter, transaction time) . Do you also think that?

Comment: Making a table temporal is a bit more involved than simply adding a Transaction Time column. Temporality requires the data to follow a certain pattern as I mentioned. But ignoring that for the moment, your original thesis is faulty. The PK of a versioned or mono-temporal table is the merging of the EPK with the valid date field. For a bi-temporal table, it is the further addition of the transaction field. So if this was an actual bi-temporal table, the primary key would be (first name, last name, parameter, valid start time, transaction time). So your teacher is correct in that respect.

Comment: @TommCatt Thanks, well if this is the case then I don't see the problem with the table.. the patient was prescribed with the medication on two occasions.. If you're saying the transaction time can be the same then what's the problem?

Comment: @Gil-Mor There is no problem with the table. The table has a popular, though somewhat cumbersome, bi-temporal design. The problem is that the data you show is not temporal data. Temporal data shows an unbroken sequence of states, with no gaps and no overlaps between the valid times periods. For example, the valid time for one of the medication entries and the fever could well be the same which would not be allowed with temporal data. You show independent events, not temporal state changes.

Comment: @Gil-Mor Another example: You show a drug being administered or prescribed at 2:09. This prescription ends at 3:18. What does this mean -- that it "ends" at 3:18? What happens at that time? A second dose is administered at 2:46 and "ends" at 3:18. What is happening from 2:46 to 3:18, the period when both events are valid at the same time? This data does not form any kind of temporal pattern.

Comment: @TommCatt The valid times don't overlap because it's not the same date. Second,  I don't get into the technical details of the medical stuff.. (If I'll do for a second so let's say the medicine was administered via Infusion btween the valid times but I don't think that's the point..).

Comment: @Gil-Mor Ok, I missed the date difference, but that means instead of an overlap, you have a gap -- also not allowed with temporal data. Still, you just verified that instead of temporal data you have a list of independent events. Instead of "valid" dates, they should be "started" and "ended".

Comment: @TommCatt, I've read several definitions of Temporal DBs and I didn't encounter the constraint you're talking about.. For example: I don't think my medical record has rows that says I'm healthy as long as I don't have any other condition. I think medical records can have gaps between the Valid Times. I guess that there are Temporal Tables where this is not the case.

Comment: @Gil-Mor If you've read anything about Temporal DBs, you must have come across something by Tom Johnston. Here is a link to a PPT by him. Check particularly slides 8-12.

Comment: @TommCatt I don't see the link. can you post again? I will read it.. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.damaflorida.wildapricot.org/Resources/Documents/Dr%20Johnston%2020100520.pptx